# Why doesn't PHP read this array and show an error?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, warnings

maybe someone can explain to me what's wrong here? Why doesn't PHP read this array, and shows an error instead?

> Warning: Undefined array key "ref" in ... on line 70

Line 70 is:

```
$ref = $_GET["ref"];
```

I want to take a variable from this input

```
<input type="text" name="ref" id="log"/>
```

Comment: Are you checking that the URL contains a relevant QueryString? Like `yoursite.com?ref=1`

Comment: How are you submitting that input data to the server? A form? Some JavaScript with AJAX? Or what? And are you doing it via a GET or POST request? We can't solve your problem with the minimal information provided.